# How to sort legend values efficiently in QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, raster, print-composer

Using QGIS 2.0, I have a vertical color legend for raster values, created in the print composer. I want the values sorted in descending order from top to bottom, which appears to be the reverse of the default order. I have found that I can manually re-order each individual item in the legend's properties by clicking the up and down arrows with that item selected. Is there a more efficient approach? The best answer would provide something (is the legend a class?) that I can manipulate with the Python console.

Comment: I've tried sorting the values in a saved qgis color map, but that isn't doing the trick.

Comment: If nothing else, thank you for alerting me that the legend can be re-ordered with the arrows. It's tedious, but it's better than nothing!